# why axios send OPTIONS request method not DELETE or PUT method

Tags: reactjs, axios

why I use axios.delete(url) or axios.put() to send request, but when I check request from NetWork in Chrome Dev Tools the Request Method is OPTIONS and Access-Control-Request-Method is DELETE or PUT like this:

[image]

Comment: Your are sending the request to an endpoint that does not exists.

Comment: @Hosar Of course I send Delete method. But it send Options request. That why I asking in here

Answer (score 2):

`DELETE` or `PUT` (or other non-simple) requests first send out a *preflighted* `OPTIONS` request to determine if you're allowed to send this request. The request method is given in the `Access-Control-Request-Method` header.

See more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests

Comment: Maybe you have. But you get a 404, so it will not proceed to send the `DELETE` or `PUT` request.

Comment: I think I get a 404 because the request is OPTIONS not DELETE.

Comment: what is the backend? If it's IIS you probably need to add the OPTIONSVerbHandler

Comment: Yeah, you have to support OPTIONS to support CORS. An easy way (but no the "correct" way) is to intercept any `OPTIONS` requests, set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to whatever is needed and then return status 200.

Comment: @Tony  I don’t really know. I work in frontend, the manager just send the API to me. I test the API before and it have not any problem. So I thought the problem is from frontend.

Comment: @Phillip  got it. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Axios uses JSON as the default content type, the call was always going with a browser as a OPTIONS call not a POST method. To overcome, we need to set the ‘Content-Type’ correctly. My configuration as following

```
let config={
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}
return axios.post(postUrl,postJson,config).then(response=>{
     return response.data;
 }).catch(error=>{
     return error;
 });
```